# Excel 2013: Powerpivot distinct count function counts empty cells

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, distinct-values

Hi I'm using the powerpivot add-in for my excel 2013, as I want to have the distinct count function in my pivot tables.

I'm however experiencing that when I make a pivot table from my data table it counts the blank/empty cells also.

E.g. If I was suppose to have 4 unique I get 5 (as there also are blanks)

Does this makes sense
Thanks
Kristoffer

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table2[nums]), Table2[nums] <> BLANK())
```

---

Images to help:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I will need it on the pivottable? Can I make calculations there?

Comment: Yes, you have to do it in your power pivot table. Select the pivot table. look for calculated fields and create a new calculated field. Here enter your formula (above in the solution). I've tested it and it works. I'll add a couple of images to the solution to help.